# How to sum textbox (value from database) and html textbox (input manually) in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

How to sum **textboxA** (got value from database) * **textboxB** (type the value manually)

I want to do =    **price * qty - disc = total**

Where value of **price** is generated from database just want the calculation,

here is the code

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'a.karat');
if(isset($_POST['product_id']))
{
    
    $prno=$_POST['prno'];
    $i=1;
    $sql = mysqli_query($con,"select * from detail_pr where prNo='$prno'");
    while ($r = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
    
        echo 
    
        '<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" id="check'.$i.'"    value="'.$i.'"></td>
    <td><label for="productCode"></label>
      <input type="text" name="productCode'.$i.'" id="productCode'.$i.'" readonly value="'.$r["productCode"].'" ></td>
    <td><label for="productName"></label>
      <input type="text" name="productName'.$i.'" id="productName'.$i.'" readonly value="'.$r["productName"].'"></td>
    <td><label for="qty"></label>
      <input type="text" name="price'.$i.'" id="price'.$i.'" readonly value="'.$r["qty"].'" ></td>
     <td><input type="text" name="qty'.$i.'" id="qty'.$i.'"  ></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="disc'.$i.'" id="disc'.$i.'" ></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="total'.$i.'" id="total'.$i.'"  ></td>
  </tr>';
  $i++;
    }
}
?>


<script type="text/javascript">
function calculate(id){
var quantity = document.getElementById('qty'+id).value;
var price = document.getElementById('price'+id).value;
var sum = parseInt(quantity,10)*parseInt(price,10); 
document.getElementById('total'+id).value = sum;
}
</script>
```

> I want to know  how to  do
>
> price * qty - disc = total

can anyone help me?

thanks

Comment: that code give you some error?

Comment: no result and no error, i don't know is my code works or not

Comment: @Alra did you call the calculate(id) function properly?

Comment: in my code above it should be qty not quantity, i have check the id, there all match, but still doesn't works, if you @ Abdul Rahman A Samad have an example just like mine, I really appreciate if you share it.  thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function calculate(id){
var quantity = document.getElementById('qty'+id).value;
//alert("quantity: " + quantity);
var price = document.getElementById('price'+id).value;
//alert("price: " + price);
var disc = document.getElementById('disc'+id).value;
//alert("disc: " + disc);
var sum = (parseInt(quantity,10)*parseInt(price,10)) - (parseInt(disc,10));
document.getElementById('total'+id).value = sum;
}
</script>
```

Comment: still doesn't work @carlos Gonzales, do i need a form to make it works?